# How to remove or fix extra space created by Expanded widgets that are wrapping the DefaultTabController and TabBarView?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I've been tweaking the TabBar widget to make the TabBarView to appear above the TabBar, since then i'd have to use the Expanded widget to wrap around the DefaultTabController and TabBarView widget to make them visible in the rendered screen. But some how, it has create some unwanted space between the TabBarView and the TabBar. That space, i believed from Expanded, is pushing all the space possible to fill the entire screen. I want to remove or control that space. How can i do that?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,        
        appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        title: 
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
          child: Text('Logo')), 
        actions: 
          [Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 20),
            child: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.menu), 
            color: Colors.white,),
          )
          ],
        ),
        body: 
          Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: DefaultTabController(length: 3, child: 
                      Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: TabBarView(
                              children: [
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  Image.asset('lib/images/Truck2.png', height: 300,),
                                  ],
                              ),
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  Image.asset('lib/images/Truck2.png', height: 300,),
                                  ],
                              ),
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  Image.asset('lib/images/Truck2.png', height: 300,),
                                ],
                              ),
                              
                              
                              ]
                            ),
                          ),
                          TabBar(tabs: [
                           Tab(
                            iconMargin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1, horizontal: 200),
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                              fixedSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(100, 38)),
                              backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.grey)),
                            onPressed: null, child: Text('Tab1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white) ,)),),
                           Tab(
                            iconMargin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1, horizontal: 200),
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                              fixedSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(100, 38)),
                              backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.grey)),
                            onPressed: null, child: Text('Tab2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white) ,)),),
                           Tab(child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                              fixedSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(100, 38)),
                              backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.grey)),
                            onPressed: null, child: Text('Tab3', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white) ,)),)
                      ]
                      ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ),
              ),
              // Container(
              //   height: 100,
              //   width: 100,
              //   color: Colors.grey,
              // ),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Button Bottom')),
              
              
            ],
          ) ,
        
            )

    )       
    ;
  }
}
```

[Trying to remove the space between tabbar and image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9y9M.png)

**All things i've tried but didn't work:
**Adjusting the flex property of the 2 expanded widgets.
Swapping Expanded to Flexible widget.
Put Sizedbox with fixed height on each image.
Delve into DevTool to see what other properties i can tweak in whichever widget.
Change mainAxisSize to be min.

Comment: What do you want in the space below the Logo and above the Truck images?  Please share a mockup of what you want the layout to look like.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the extra space between image and the tabbars below. I just want the tabbars to go directly below the image. I illustrated it on the image. I don't exactly have the final mockup, but i know i will have more things below the tabbars. Please take a look. If there isn't anything below i can put below to fill in the space, i guess the only thing i can do is to put an empty sizebox to for it to take up the space... what do you think? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Maybe you want an Expanded( child: Placeholder() ) there for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this closer to what you want? It doesn't sound like you really want the DefaultTabController to be expanded.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: null,
          title: const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20), child: Text('Logo')),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 20),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            DefaultTabController(
              length: 3,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 350,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBarView(children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/Truck2.png',
                              height: 300,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/Truck2.png',
                              height: 300,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/Truck2.png',
                              height: 300,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ),
                    TabBar(tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        iconMargin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1, horizontal: 200),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                                fixedSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(100, 38)),
                                backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.grey)),
                            onPressed: null,
                            child: const Text(
                              'Tab1',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            )),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        iconMargin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1, horizontal: 200),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                                fixedSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(100, 38)),
                                backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.grey)),
                            onPressed: null,
                            child: const Text(
                              'Tab2',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            )),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                                fixedSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(100, 38)),
                                backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.grey)),
                            onPressed: null,
                            child: const Text(
                              'Tab3',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            )),
                      )
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(child: Placeholder()),
            ElevatedButton(child: Text('bottom button'), onPressed: null)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Nice. What did you adjust? Thank you! I see that even if i remove the Flexible widget, it still stay up there. Also, do you mind sharing your thought process when thinking about an issue like this?

Comment: I'm not great at layout issues.  But I generally try to think about what parts of the layout will be a fixed size and what areas I want to be able to expand to fill the available space. I also, don't try to add everything at once.  Instead, I think about the layout and add one piece at a time.